# hsqldb procedure with date Input parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hsqldb, procedure

I need to write a test for some download operation. This operation call procedure from MSSQL database, take result set and java make some stuf. For test I use hsqldb.

```
My procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE map.Get1(IN packageName varchar(100), 
IN downloadDate DATE) 
READS SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM map.tvschedule FOR READ ONLY; 
OPEN result; 
END
```

This procedure wan't work, i have an exception

call map.GET1('Genre','2018-03-10');

```
[42561][-5561] incompatible data type in conversion
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type 
in conversion
```

But this(without date parameter) work well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE map.Get1(IN packageName varchar(100)) 
READS SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM map.tvschedule FOR READ ONLY; 
OPEN result; 
END
```

call map.GET1('Genre');

**first needed row**

**second needed row**

I am not going to use input parameter, but i need this procedure to be looking i am going to.

**My question is How to use date input parameter with hsqldb procedures?**

**UPDATE1:**
I used TO_DATE and now it works well, but i have no data in my result set, my java code is:

```
try (CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call 
map.GetGenreProtocol( ?, ? ) }")) {
        callableStatement.setString(1, packageName);
        callableStatement.setDate(2, date);
        callableStatement.execute();
        ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet();


        while (resultSet.next()) {

           Interval Interval = new Interval();
            Interval.setDuration(resultSet.getInt("duration"));
           Interval.setMappingTargetId(resultSet.getInt("mappingTargetId"));
            Interval.setGenreId(resultSet.getInt("genreId"));
            Interval.setStart(resultSet.getLong("start"));
            Interval.setCategoryId(resultSet.getInt("categoryId"));
            Interval.setCategoryName(resultSet.getString("categoryName"));
            Interval.setGenreName(resultSet.getString("genreName"));
            Interval.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));

            Intervals.add(Interval);
        }
    }
```

Comment: add `callableStatement.getMoreResults()` after `callableStatement.execute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TO_DATE` function.

For example:

```
call map.GET1('Genre', TO_DATE('2018-03-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I guess you need to create a function that returns a table instead of a procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION map.Get1(IN packageName  VARCHAR(100),
                         IN downloadDate DATE)
  RETURNS TABLE(.....)
  READS SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
  ....
END;
```

Comment: It's working, but result set is null. Could you help me with it? I added code of my class to first post.